# How to change the Width of a DataGridTemplateColumn without using a converter?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn, whose Width I'd like to change based on the related boolean property.
Now I'm using a converter as shown in the code below in order to achieve my purpose.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="{Binding IsFull, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToColumnWidthConverter}}">
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

public class BooleanToColumnWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly DataGridLength NORMAL_WIDTH = new DataGridLength(10, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

    private static readonly DataGridLength NARROWED_WIDTH = new DataGridLength(3, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is bool)) { return  DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; }

        var isFull = (bool) value;
        return isFull ? FULL_WIDTH : NARROWED_WIDTH;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get the same result without using a converter, for example by defining something like a style or a template as shown in the following?

```
<!-- This does not compile. -->
<Style TargetType="DataGridTemplateColumn">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="10*"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFull}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="3*"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709325/1136211

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for your reply. I know CellStyle, but it is different from my purpose. I'd like to set a style or a template for DataGridTemplateColumn itself, not for a Cell or a Header.